# How do i get the internet working on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: network-manager

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my old AMD FX 8320 machine and I can't get the internet working on it. I keep getting an error saying "authentication of network connection failed". I also cant seem to find the additional drivers section anymore so I cant verify if the network adapter is even activated.

I don't know much about my system but I believe the mainboard has an Intel network card, according to gigabyte anyway.

Update: I am using the wired network but did try a wireless dongle but greeted me with the same result. I have pasted `sudo lshw -c network` into the terminal and this is what spat out.

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: enp5s0
       version: 03
       serial: 1c:1b:0d:97:d0:e1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:fe100000-fe11ffff ioport:d000(size=32) memory:fe120000-fe123fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:4
       logical name: wlx98ded017fca6
       serial: 98:de:d0:17:fc:a6
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Is this WiFi? This Question is way to broad.

Comment: Paste Results of this ```sudo lshw -c network``` into your Question.

Comment: I have updated the post with what I typed and the end results from the terminal. I must confess that I don't really know much about this and could have done a better job with what network adapter i was using

Comment: What do you call "internet connection"? Is it a wired or a wireless connection? It looks like you are using some USB wireless dongle. Are you trying to use it to connect?

Comment: @EODCraftStaff Use code-blocks in edits like this.

Comment: I've tried both wired and wireless and neither are working. when I mean internet, I mean I want to get online so I can do updates and download the driver for my Nvidia graphics card